# Joining Tables in Django ORM with Left Outer Join and Additional Condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I'm trying to perform a left outer join between two models in Django using the ORM. I need to include an additional condition within the ON clause of the join to filter the results based on specific criteria.

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    book_title = model.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, db_column='author')
```

Is there a way to retrieve all the book objects along with the name of the author where the title and `book_title` are equal? The SQL will look like this:

```sql
select title, author, name as author_name from book left outer join author on 
(book.author = author.id AND book.title = author.book_title)
```

Since the table is very large ( 13m ) I cannot resort to raw query because I will lose the ability to use PageNumberPagination. I don't want to use extra because this may lead to problems in the future. Is there any other way I can achieve the above SQL using Django orm??

Comment: why does book_title exist on author, you are already having author-book 0-many relationship?

Answer (score 1):

You can work with an [**`F`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F):

```
from django.db.models import F

Book.objects.filter(title=F('author__book_title'))
```

or if you want to have something functionally equivalent as including it in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
from django.db.models import Case, F, When

Book.objects.annotate(
    author_name=Case(
        When(title=F('author__book_title'), then=F('author__name')), default=None
    )
)
```

It however looks very strange that an `Author` has a `book_title` field. This would essentially imply an `Author` can only have one book? Even if that is somehow the case, it would be a form of *data duplication*, and it turns out that keeping data in sync is not as easy as it may look like.

Comment: author in same time can have many books :) seems like bad db design

Comment: @iklinac: well even it could only have one book, it seems useless and problematic to store it in the `Author` model: if the book title changes (for example due to a typo), the troubles begin.

Comment: Book.objects.filter(title=F('author__book_title')) will only create a left outer join with one condition on book.author = author.id. Yes the db design is bad, its an archaic project client wanted to migrate to django. However is there no way in django for adding another condition in cases like this?

Comment: @AbdulRahman.: you can mimic that behavior with a case-when, that will use `NULL` in case the `ON` does not match, it makes it actually more explicit what the problem is with the database design. I would not call it archaic, since in the old days, database normal forms tend to be more respected than now.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is a fool proof solution but that subtle hack does save the day as far as I am concerned. Thank you!!

But I am not sure whether this will for more complex scenarios such as this 
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29262

Comment: @AbdulRahman.: well a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` essentially sets something to `NULL` if it can not find/match, so here we use `author_name=NULL` given `title` is not `book_title`.